# how do i fix my read only hard drive?

Tags: 13.10, filesystem, hardware

I did try dmesg
now i't able write for a little bit and then it will go to read only
this is it says when i make a folder
Error while creating directory Untitled Folder.
There was an error creating the directory in /home/steven/Desktop.
Show more details
Error creating directory: Read-only file system
and this what happens when i use dmesg

*[  306.948404] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]

[  306.948408] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed

[  306.948411] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
 
[  306.948413] Read(10): 28 00 01 a7 e0 00 00 01 00 00

[  306.948425] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 27779072

[  306.948452] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Unhandled sense code

[  306.948455] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]

[  306.948457] Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  306.948460] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]

[  306.948462] Sense Key : Medium Error [current] [descriptor]

[  306.948466] Descriptor sense data with sense descriptors (in hex):

[  306.948468]         72 03 11 04 00 00 00 0c 00 0a 80 00 00 00 00 00

[  306.948480]         00 a5 e7 e8
 
[  306.948485] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda]
 
[  306.948488] Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error - auto reallocate failed

[  306.948491] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] CDB:
 
[  306.948493] Read(10): 28 00 00 a5 e7 e8 00 00 08 00

[  306.948503] end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 10872808

[  306.948516] ata1: EH complete

[  318.650230] EXT4-fs (dm-0): error count: 12

[  318.650241] EXT4-fs (dm-0): initial error at 1388027997: ext4_find_entry:1309: inode 11929652

[  318.650248] EXT4-fs (dm-0): last error at 1388075100: ext4_journal_check_start:56: inode 11929652

[  348.647597] init: anacron main process (1046) terminated with status 1

[  357.072138] EXT4-fs error (device dm-0): ext4_remount:4746: Abort forced by user

[  358.271328] init: Failed to write to log file /var/log/upstart/plexmediaserver.log*

Comment: This does sound like there may be filesystem errors. When this happens, do include the contents of `dmesg` within your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Press Ctrl + Alt + F1 and login.

Try

```
sudo mount -o remount,rw /dev/sd? /
```

To get the sd? you have to run `df` and the one that mounted at `/` is the proper one.

That should work.

When done, Ctrl + Alt + F7.

This may not be persistent through reboot. This is *most likely* temporary.

Comment: it says sudo: unable to open var/lib/sudo/steven/tty1: read only file system